# Rails 3 extract the domain of a link with a regex and print it in parens,

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

`Rails -v 3.2.3`

I'm working with an app that is supposed to display a description & url of a submitted link, I am using regex operators, which is something i am very new too. here is my views code:

`(<%= if link.url =~ /(:\/\/) ([^\/]*)/ then $2 else "wrong URL" end %>)`

however with every link i submit, the url is always `wrong URL`.... 
is this because $2 is the wrong regex operator? or is the `/(:\/\/) ([^\/]*)/` section incorrect in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill that space in the middle!  The regex you're showing expects a space between the `://` and the `sub.domain.tld` chunks; since no URLs have that, the regex won't match anything.  The simplest change should be:

```
/(:\/\/)([^\/]*)/
```

Or, to clean it up a little more (you don't need the first pair of parentheses):

```
(<%= if link.url =~ /:\/\/([^\/]*)/ then $1 else "wrong URL" end %>)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: awesome! this did the trick, thank you so much!! regexp is really weird to me for some reason... can you point in the direction of any decent resources for me to catch up on?